# Spring boot throwing DataIntegrityViolationException when inserting into My SQL from many tomcat instances

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have 6 instances of my application running in production and I have exposed a REST service which when called with the parameters will create a record in a MySQL table.

I am seeing some records failing to insert with `DataIntegrityViolationException` in my logs. Less than 1% I should say. If I check its values and manually trigger my service feeding these values then it works fine, which tells me its not data related.

I got a auto increment field in my table. Can it be because of that? Where more than one instances are getting allocated the same Id.

> Exception is {
>   org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not
>   execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement

I got `@Transactional` at class level and using named queries to insert record into the table.
 This is not happening for every record but sporadically.

I am using spring boot, and Hibernate annotations to insert records.

Comment: Post more details about the stacktrace (full version of it, if you have access to that) and named query itself

Comment: Your nested exception is `DataException` with explanation: "Implementation of JDBCException indicating that evaluation of the valid SQL statement against the given data resulted in some illegal operation, mismatched types or incorrect cardinality." It would make sense if you could post the statement you're trying to execute

Comment: @Zilvinas - Thank You. Actually after deep diving I see that I was trying to insert a larger value into a small length column. Can you please post your comment as a reply and I shall accept it.

Comment: Thank you @ali-dehghani too